# Azure: Upload whitelist certificate to application gateway

Tags: azure, ssl

I'm trying to activate end-to-end encryption in Azure. I have created all the required components through the portal. I follow these instructions: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-end-to-end-ssl-powershell)

I'm stuck at step 7. I'd like to whitelist the certificate.

Since I haven't worked with Power Shell before, I can't follow the instructions exactly. Can this step also be done in the portal?

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I remember portal UI doesnt allow to do that yet. you can use powershell and\or arm templates to do that. you have the powershell example, here's the arm template example.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-application-gateway-2vms-iis-ssl/azuredeploy.json#L618